# SPFx CustomAction sequence / default action

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-framework

My goal is to create an extension for **Sharepoint Online** that adds a context menu entry to the *top* of the context menu for specific files in Document Libraries and lists and is the default action for those items.

For the classic experience this is easily doable with an Add-In by using the following XML:

```
<CustomAction 
    RegistrationType="FileType"
    RegistrationId="txt"
    Location="EditControlBlock"
    Sequence="0"
    Title="TestApplication">
</CustomAction>
```

Here I can specify that my CustomAction only targets certain files with `RegistrationType` and I can specify the extension by using `RegistrationId`. The order in the context menu is given by the `Sequence` attribute, where 0 is top of the list.

Sadly, as I understand it, I have to use SPFx for the New Experience UI and here we have to check during runtime if the selected item corresponds to a specific file type. So I **can** replicate the `RegistrationType` / `RegistrationId` functionality although that is not supported in CustomAction XML.

What I don't understand is how to replicate the `Sequence` functionality so that my context menu item appears as first item in the context menu and/or how I can set my action as default action that will be executed when the list item is double clicked.

I appreciate any advice. Thanks.

PS. If there is another way to achive this with something else than SPFx I'd be glad for any pointers.

Comment: Assuming you are building a list view command set extension ? You can specify the sequence in your clientsideinstance.xml file.However it is used when there are multiple extensions loading on the same scope. See the documentation here : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/basics/tenant-wide-deployment-extensions

Comment: That is not the functionality that I am looking for. I want to specify the position of a context menu entry and not the order in which extensions are loaded.The question is how I can achieve something like what is described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh500259(v=office.14)#custom-action-elements) under the "Squence" attribute but for the New Experience UI.